# How to add custom MetricFilter in GraphiteReporter to send only selected metricd

Tags: java, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I have implemented Dropwizard metrics in my application. I am sending metrics to Graphite using below code.

```
final Graphite graphite = new Graphite(new InetSocketAddress("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxx));
final GraphiteReporter graphiteReporter = GraphiteReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry)
                .prefixedWith(getReporterRootTagName())
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .filter(MetricFilter.ALL)
                .build(graphite);

        graphiteReporter.start(Integer.parseInt(getTimePeriod()), timeUnit);
```

I want to add custom MetricFilter so that instead of sending all metrics to Graphite only few specific metrics will be sent.

eg. max,mean,min,mean only.

Please post MetricFilter usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you could implement a metric filter:

```java
class WhitelistMetricFilter implements MetricFilter {
    private final Set<String> whitelist;

    public WhitelistMetricFilter(Set<String> whitelist) {
        this.whitelist = whitelist;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String name, Metric metric) {
        for (String whitelisted: whitelist) {
            if (whitelisted.endsWith(name))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I suggest checking the names using `String#endsWith` function as the name you get there is not the full metric name usually (for example it may not contain your prefix). With this filter you can instantiate your reporter:

```java
final MetricFilter whitelistFilter = new WhitelistMetricFilter(whitelist);
final GraphiteReporter reporter = GraphiteReporter
    .forRegistry(metricRegistry)
    .prefixedWith(getReporterRootTagName())
    .filter(whiltelistFilter)
    .build(graphite);
```

This should do the trick. If you need more refined filtering on the metrics - for example if you need to disable specific metrics reported automatically by timers, then [3.2.0](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/releases/tag/v3.2.0) version introduced this. You can use the `disabledMetricAttributes` argument to provide a set of attributes that you want to be disabled.

```java
final Set<MetricAttribute> disabled = new HashSet<MetricAttribute>();
disabled.add(MetricAttribute.MAX);

final GraphiteReporter reporter = GraphiteReporter
    .forRegistry(metricRegistry)
    .disabledMetricAttributes(disabled)
    .build(graphite)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I think I didn't post my question correctly. Actually i want to filter the Timer metrics **count
         mean rate 
     1-minute rate 
     5-minute rate
    15-minute rate 
               min 
               max 
              mean 
            stddev
            median 
              75% 
              95% 
              98% 
              99% 
            99.9%**    I want some way to send only selected ones to Graphite.

Comment: Hmm, so you're looking to filter all these out / in? The ones you listed are reported by timers / meters. If you want to filter all these out it should be easy. If you want only a part of them there is a nasty workaround but it should work - so which one is it?

Comment: Yes you got right, i want only **count, mean, min, max**  and moreover is it feasible to have X mins duration in Timer metrics apart from default 1,5,15mins?

Comment: What version of codahale metrics are you using? The 3.2.0 GraphiteReporter has an argument `disabledMetricAttributes`. You can use that one :) Let me know if that works for you and I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks, 3.2.0 works :) You seem to have worked a lot in codehale metrics.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Actually not that much - I just had some nasty issues to solve as well. I'll edit the answer to provide further details :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137654/discussion-between-andrei-t-and-mayank-singh).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue can be solved using disabledMetricAttributes.

In the accepted answer, this would work better:

if (name.endsWith(whitelisted))