# Is it possible on Flink to decide which metrics are being send to Graphite?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

So far we used the GraphiteReporter to monitor the Flink. Recently, we decided that we don't need all the metrics that are being reported to the Graphite, and we would like to know if it's possible to still use the GraphiteReporter but control the type and amount of metrics that are been sent.

Comment: I Think u can have the response of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570419/how-to-add-custom-metricfilter-in-graphitereporter-to-send-only-selected-metricd)